# Laravel + Vue.js - How to pass data from Controller to vue

Tags: vue.js, laravel-8

I am wanting to pass the data from my app controller to my vue:

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return response()
            ->view('pages.app', ['highScore' => HighScore::getHighScore()], 200);
    }
}
```

Here is my routes managed in vue:

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: Home,
        meta: { bodyClass: 'page' },
        props: true
    },
]
```

Now within my home view I am populating the following within props:

```
props: ['highScore']
```

But it is undefined, any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can axios to make laravel api calls.

Comment: @dev, thanks, I am wanting to reduce the amount of calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller you pass the data as usual from controller to a blade view. I use this syntax:

[image]

Then, on the Blade View you have to add the VueJs component and pass the same data like this:

[image]

Now you can access all those variables on the Vue component.

Answer (score 0):

In the jetsteam/inertia setup it's done like this:

```
Route::get('/page4', function () {
    $allusers = ['aa','bb','cc'];
    return Inertia::render('Page4',
        ['users' => $allusers]);
})
```

If it's a new projet? i recomment this, cause it makes it easier.
https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/stacks/inertia.html

Comment: I am aware of that solution but I am extending a current project that does not use Jetstream

Comment: Check if passing to an normal blade works and check what values for your variables  the vue extension for chrome shows.